# На чем лучше основывать менеджер(контроллер) страниц у приложения

Tags: python, qt

Использую qt и python. Вопрос такой, в каком виде лучше реализовывать страницы приложения, такие как авторизация, главная, об программе итд. Есть несколько вариантов:

- каждая страница это новое окно
- каждая страница это новый слой
- каждая страница это новая вкладка

Какой вариант лучше использовать? Может еще есть варианты

Comment: Есть такое понятие, как User Friendly...  И даже профессия отдельная - дизайнер интерфейсов. Делать нужно не как удобно разработчику, а как конечному пользователю.

Comment: Конечный пользователь не заметит разницы. Все будет в одном окне, а смену страниц разными способами реализовать можно. Скрыть одно окно показать другое. Или скрыть один слой включить другой итд

Comment: скрывать слои и окна тоже можно по разному. В общем случае это ресурсозатратно делается.

Comment: если вам нужно переключать страницы приложения в одном окне согласно какой-то отдельной логике, то берите `QStackedWidget`. Если нужны вкладки, по которым пользователь перемещается сам, то QTabWidget

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Кажется то, что нужно! Это нормальная практика так делить страницу логина, главную, настроек, о программе итд?

Comment: я бы сказал, это самое оптимальное решение

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!